# Easy way to pause execution and wait for key press in VBA?

Tags: vba

I would like to have a VBA macro pause its execution and wait for the user to press a key before continuing.  Is there a quick way to accomplish this, or am I better off using a window popup?

Answer (score 3):

A warning: In my experience, unless your VBA specifically includes DoEvents statements, Office applications are unresponsive while VBA is running.

If you only want to interrupt a process temporarily until the user is ready, then using a pop-up is by far the simplest method.

Adding something like the following would have the desired result:

```
Msgbox "Click to go on", , "Example"
```

The user would click to continue or could hit enter or space.

If you wanted a more specific pop-up, loading a modal userform (in Excel) or a modal form (in Access) from code will halt the suspend the calling code until the form is closed.

Honestly, I would resist including a pause unless it's absolutely necessary. Any unnecessary interuption is an annoyance and hinderance to efficiency. If you simply want to inform the user about what is happening you can update the screen to explain what the code is doing as it performs actions.